# Javascript rotate - how to rotate counterclockwise?

Tags: javascript, jquery, rotation

I have two shapes that I made to rotate on scroll. I was able to rotate them clockwise, however I would like the second shape to rotate counterclockwise.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7tLv05on/

Here is the following code I used to achieve that:

```
var sdegree = 0;

$(window).scroll(function() {

sdegree ++ ;
sdegree = sdegree + 2 ;

var srotate = "rotate(" + sdegree + "deg)";

$(".move1").css({"-moz-transform" : srotate, "-webkit-transform" : srotate});
$(".move2").css({"-moz-transform" : srotate, "-webkit-transform" : srotate});

});
```

Thank you I really appreciate the help!

Comment: Look at my answer:)

Comment: Thank you for all of the variety of responses everyone!!

Comment: Glad you got it working:) @user3663071

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do it like this:

```
  var sdegree = 0;
  var sdegree2 = 0;

  $(window).scroll(function() {

    sdegree ++ ;
    sdegree = sdegree + 2 ;

    sdegree2 -- ;
    sdegree2 = sdegree2 - 2 ;

    var srotate = "rotate(" + sdegree + "deg)";
    var srotate2 = "rotate(" + sdegree2 + "deg)";

    $(".move1").css({"-moz-transform" : srotate, "-webkit-transform" : srotate});
    $(".move2").css({"-moz-transform" : srotate2, "-webkit-transform" : srotate2});

  });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var sdegree = 0;

$(window).scroll(function() {

    sdegree ++ ;
    sdegree = sdegree + 2 ;

    var srotate = "rotate(" + sdegree + "deg)";

    $(".move1").css({"-moz-transform" : srotate, "-webkit-transform" : srotate});

    //negative degree
    var sdegree2 = -sdegree;
    srotate = "rotate(" + sdegree2 + "deg)";
    $(".move2").css({"-moz-transform" : srotate, "-webkit-transform" : srotate});

});
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7tLv05on/6/)

Answer (score 0):

Just multiply value by -1 and that's it:

```
var sdegree = 0;

$(window).scroll(function() {

sdegree ++ ;
sdegree = sdegree + 2 ;

var cwRotate = "rotate(" + sdegree + "deg)",
    ccwRotate = "rotate(" + (-1 * sdegree) + "deg)";

$(".move1").css({"-moz-transform" : cwRotate, "-webkit-transform" : cwRotate});
$(".move2").css({"-moz-transform" : ccwRotate, "-webkit-transform" : ccwRotate});

});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7tLv05on/5/

Comment: I see it now, but my code is a little bit shortest and uses only 1 more variable.